# Why is my Material Date Picker not using custom format

Tags: angular-material, date-fns

In my root module I'm setting up a DateAdapter and custom formats that I hoped the angular-material Datepicker would then use. My providers array is as follows:

```
  providers: [
    { provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: enGB },
    {
      provide: MAT_DATE_FNS_FORMATS,
      useValue: {
        parse: { dateInput: 'dd/MM/yy' },
        display: {
          dateInput: 'dd/MM/yy',
          monthYearLabel: 'MM/yy',
          dateA11yLabel: 'dd/MM/yy',
          monthYearA11yLabel: 'MM/yy',
        },
      },
    },
    {
      provide: DateAdapter,
      useClass: DateFnsAdapter,
      deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE, MAT_DATE_FNS_FORMATS],
    },
  ],
```

However my datepicker is stubbornly continuing to show and format dates with a 4 digit date.  Is there something else I need to do. I'm just dropping the date picker on the form like this:

```
        <mat-form-field>
          <mat-label>My Date</mat-label>
          <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker1" #mydate id="mydate" formControlName="myDate" />
          <mat-hint>DD/MM/YY</mat-hint>
          <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker1"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
          <mat-datepicker #picker1></mat-datepicker>
        </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: I used the solution in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65581116/how-can-i-format-the-angular-material-datepicker-without-moment-js-dependency

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `DateAdapter` and the names for the constants have been changed, the following imports and definitions worked for me

```js
import {
  MAT_DATE_LOCALE,
  MAT_DATE_FORMATS
} from '@angular/material/core';

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
providers: [{
    provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE,
    useValue: 'en-GB'
  },
  {
    provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS,
    useValue: {
      parse: {
        dateInput: 'DD/MM/yy'
      },
      display: {
        dateInput: 'DD/MM/yy',
        monthYearLabel: 'MM/yy',
        dateA11yLabel: 'DD/MM/yy',
        monthYearA11yLabel: 'MM/yy',
      },
    },
  },
  //   {
  //     provide: DateAdapter,
  //     useClass: DateAdapter,
  //     deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE, MAT_DATE_FORMATS],
  //   },
]
```

Comment: That still didn't work for me, but many thanks for responding. I instead used the approach in my answer below